# What does the `--tmp` flag do when running the Substrate Node Template?

Tags: cli, dev

The [Substrate Node Template](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template) says in the "Run" section of the README, that the single-node development chain will start with "non-persistent state" if run with the following command:

```
cargo run --release --dev --tmp
```

The Substrate Node's `--help` file says `--dev` specifies the development chain and sets, among other things, the `--tmp` flag.

But, what is `--tmp` is supposed to do? The node seems to run fine with only `--dev`. I can't find `--tmp` in `--help` either.

Also, if `--help` is accurate, then the `--tmp` doesn't need to be specified alongside `--dev`, and that may just be a mistake in the README?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Every blockchain maintains some amount of state on the computer which it runs. For example to store information about the history of the blockchain, the current block, the current state, etc...

When starting a Substrate blockchain with the `--tmp` flag, it will place all of these files into a temporary system folder which will be cleaned up once the program terminates. It would be equivalent to use the `--purge-chain` flag at the end of running your blockchain to delete all of the local files.

Indeed, if you have the `--dev` flag, you do not need the `--tmp` flag, since developer chains by default are now configured to be temporary by default.

Answer (score 6):

--tmp means it runs a temporary node. And it stop when you close the terminal. This way you could run your development mode without purging the data.

Comment: When you run with `--tmp`, the entire idea is that the data is purged on closing the node.

Answer (score 5):

`--tmp` will clear down the state before it starts, so rather than carrying on from the last agreed block it will start from the first block again.

But in this case it seemingly has no effect, because as of a few months ago `--dev` now implies `--tmp` by default.

Comment: I don't believe "clear down the state before it starts" is accurate. The blockchain state is placed in a temporary folder and is cleaned up as soon as the process ends.